# What will be the migrated blog.msdn links?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, referrals

There are many posts referring to https://blogs.msdn.com and we see below message.

> If you were looking for MSDN or TechNet blogs, please know that MSDN and TechNet blog sites have been retired, and blog content has been migrated and archived here.

or

> Oops, 404 Error! That page can’t be found. It looks like nothing was
> found at this location. Try one of the developer blog links below?

I tried to fix at least some of them but it looks like it will be very difficult to do this manually. I saw some of them move to the web.archive.org. So, what will be these links, the [Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) bot can't fix them?

Examples:
[How to set .net Framework 4.5 version in IIS 7 application pool](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9559372/13664939)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3045089/13664939
[Visual Studio debugging "quick watch" tool and lambda expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/725499/13664939)
[Debug .NET Framework Source Code in Visual Studio 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15185725/13664939)

Comment: Heh. And that's why we must never rely on external links: they all die one day, even if hosted on company like Microsoft. Better not spend SE dev time of this, and just remove all those links (automatically, there should be tools for that in their disposal) and if it leaves a post empty, delete the post as well as it's left useless and without value.

Comment: cross-site dupe: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394045/msdn-blog-links-are-broken-what-should-we-do-now/406565#406565

Comment: @ShadowTheVaccinatedWizard You are absolutely right.I'm tired seeing of these.

Comment: The script I mentioned in that Meta.SO answer runs on a few other sites as well (Code Review, DBA, Game Development, SharePoint); on sites where this is a smaller problem I'm doing a few manual edits now and then. The script hasn't got the time yet to arrive at the posts you mention (it edits oldest first, and not too much at once to avoid flooding the homepage/suggested edit queue).

Comment: Besides your script, I think staff has an URL rewriter as well. They used it for the HTTP > HTTPS migration. With the logic from @Glorfindel they could easily re-use that bot and make changes network wide without bumping.

Comment: @Glorfindel It is pleasing that you spend time on this. I hope that SO team will do something also.

Comment: @Luuklag the problem is that some of the pages are gone forever. And I'm not sure the URL rewriter can handle a substitution like this, IIRC it's a SQL script with limited capabilities.

Comment: That's why I said to implement your logic you mentioned [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394045/msdn-blog-links-are-broken-what-should-we-do-now/406565#406565)

Comment: @Luuklag understood; I needed regex to do that and SQL doesn't really support regex. Maybe rene knows how to do it with normal SQL functions?

Comment: You will have to start by parsing the HTML @Glorfindel

Comment: I think that an exact match could not be found yet. If you want the truth I couldn't even find the links that some of them were migrated by eye :)

Comment: @Luuklag you shall not parse HTML in T-SQL ...